# Is it possible in Google Sheets to displayed "moving" image that changes column every second?

Tags: google-apps-script

Hi I really have no idea of google apps script and I don't know if it is possible. I basicly want to know if it is worth my time to dive deeper into the material, or if it is just can't be acomplished.
So I have an Icon, that is an two frame animation basicly. So I wonder if I can have it displayed "moving".
My thought was to have something like an Index() function but the Colum number changes from 1 to 2 back and forth every second ( or if possible twice every second).
I found some couners and clocks but I don't understand enough to get any inside from them.
Maybe this is a dumb question, but I'm curious to see the answers if there are any :D
Have a great day!

```
function animate() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var range = ss.getRange(1, 1);
  var maxFrame = 4;
  for (var i = 0; i < 100; ++i) {
    var frame = (i % maxFrame) + 1;
    range.setValue(frame);
    SpreadsheetApp.flush();
    Utilities.sleep(100);
  }
}
```

I saw this one counting upwards in a cell but I couldn't get it to run.

Comment: `can have [a two-frame image] displayed "moving"` Yes. Though you must remember that there is a limit to the execution time of any function. `I'm curious to see the answers if there are any` You asked a question inviting a "Yes"/"No" answer. May I respectfully mention that StackOverflow is not a bespoke code writing service. Some users may, through own curiosity or prior work, offer examples of **a** "moving" image - which may or may not reflect your specific circumstances.

Comment: Hi, thank you very much for your comment. The Yes-answer was all I was looking for. I am new to this community and just didn't know, what type of answer this type of question would generate. I didn't know if it would be toxic, because the question I asked is not typical or if it would be just ignored, or maybe there would be someone as generous as you were, sitting down and writing a short paragraph. It was exciting for me and felt like a much needed adventure :D Since your comment guided me to stay on track I got the code I mentioned to work and it solved the problem, not ideal but a solution

Comment: That's a good outcome. Sometimes a user will ask a question similar to yours but expect a full script as an answer - hence my reticence. `I got the code I mentioned to work and it solved the problem` Why not post it as an answer. It is rarely the case that there is only one solution to any given problem.

Answer (score 0):

Out of curiosity, I created this crude example of "moving" an image.

I manually inserted a 'two-part animation' "gif" file that I found on the net.

The script moves the image between cell E10 and cell E11.

---

```
/*
// inserted an image into the spreadsheet
// didn't put it IN a cell but above a cell
*/
function movingImage() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet()

  // get all the images, returnas an array
  var images = ss.getImages()
  // Logger.log(images) // DEBUG
  
  // get the cell
  var ac = images[0].getAnchorCell()
  // Logger.log(ac.getA1Notation()) // DEBUG

  // created two cells for movement
  var targetcell1 = sheet.getRange("E10")
  var targetcell2 = sheet.getRange("E11")

  // set a runniung time
  var timeLimitSeconds = 20
  for (i=0;i<timeLimitSeconds;i++){
    // move the image to cell#1
    images[0].setAnchorCell(targetcell1)
    //SpreadsheetApp.flush(); // found this wasn't needed
    // wait
    Utilities.sleep(2*250);
    //SpreadsheetApp.flush();// found this wasn't needed
    // move the image to cell #2
    images[0].setAnchorCell(targetcell2)
  }
}
```

Comment: I am curios to check this one out! Thank you for sharing your curiosity with me. If I end up using your script. I will make shure to mention you on the Credits of the Google Sheet :D